# Aligning multiple TextView within new CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to create a CardView that will display a quote by an author, including the author name, the quote, and then the reference below it. I think I've got most of it, but it seems that the general rules for aligning TextViews don't seem to apply to CardView. I've researched here and found that you should add `android:layout="vertical"` to LinearLayout (or RelativeLayout) but that doesn't seem to change things for me. I've also tried adding it to the CardView itself, thinking that it inherits the orientation from the immediate parent, but also no luck. I still get the TextViews overlapping each other, rather than one after the other.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    ... >

<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF4444"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Gordon B. Hinckley"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/info_text"
        android:text="Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text."
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/info_text2"
        android:textColor="#33B5E5"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="and I'm the reference."
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Solved it. Just needed to wrap the `<TextView>`s in a `<LinearLayout>` (or whatever other layout) but all still within `<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was of great help.

Comment: I have used <RelativeLayout> inside <CardView> and it didn't work properly. Using <LinearLayout> works